# javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE={1} {0}

Tags: java, javafx, model-validation

Criei um formulário onde tenho os seguintes Campos Nome, Cargo, Login e Senha.
estou usando o `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE={1} {0}` para retorna mensagem de erro para o usuário. Sei que está funcionado porque todos os campos estão sendo verificado por ele, porem o campo login ele não verifica onde estou errando.

Segue baixo o Código do meu formulário:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

```
<ui:define name="content">

    <p:tabView style="width:600px;height:370px;margin:auto;">
        <p:tab title="Cadastro de Funcionário">

            <h:form id="form-cadastro">

                <h:panelGrid id="panelGrid-campos-form" columns="2"
                    cellpadding="10">

                    <p:outputLabel value="Nome:" for="inputText-nome" />
                    <p:inputText id="inputText-nome" style="width:300px"
                        value="#{cadastroFuncionarioBean.pessoaModel.nome}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Cargo:" for="inputText-cargo" />
                    <p:inputText id="inputText-cargo" style="width:300px"
                        value="#{cadastroFuncionarioBean.funcionarioModel.cargo}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Login:" for="inputText-login" />
                    <p:inputText id="inputText-login" style="width:300px"
                        value="#{cadastroFuncionarioBean.usuarioModel.nomeUsuario}"/>

                    <p:outputLabel value="Senha:" for="inputText-senha" />
                    <p:inputText id="inputText-senha" style="width:300px"
                        value="#{cadastroFuncionarioBean.usuarioModel.senha}"/>

                    <p:spacer />

                    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="commandButton-salvar"
                        icon="ui-icon-disk"
                        actionListener="#{cadastroFuncionarioBean.salvar}"
                        update="panelGrid-campos-form" />

                </h:panelGrid>

                  <p:messages showDetail="false" showSummary="true" autoUpdate="true" />            

            </h:form>

        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="Upload Xml Pessoa">

            <h:form id="form-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <h:panelGrid id="panelGrid-upload-xml" columns="2" cellpadding="10">

                    <p:fileUpload value="#{cadastroFuncionarioBean.file}"
                        mode="simple" skinSimple="true" label="Selecionar" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Importar..." ajax="false"
                        actionListener="#{cadastroFuncionarioBean.UploadRegistros}" />

                </h:panelGrid>

            </h:form>
        </p:tab>

    </p:tabView>

</ui:define>
```

Meu arquivo Messages.properties

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE={1} {0}
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message = deve ser informado.
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message = deve ter tamanho entre \ {min} e {max}.
javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin.message = deve ser maior ou \ igual a {value}.
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message = deve ser \ informado.
br.com.mensagens.NumeroDecimal.message = deve ser um número decimal \ positivo.
```

e  minha classe model com as restrições:

```
package br.com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity 
@Table(name="usuario")
public class UsuarioModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_usuario")
private Long codigo;

@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name="usuario",length = 20, nullable = false)
private String usuario;

@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 10)
@Column(name="senha",length = 10, nullable = false)
private String senha;

public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}
public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

/* Abaixo hashCode() e equals */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    UsuarioModel other = (UsuarioModel) obj;
    if (codigo == null) {
        if (other.codigo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
        return false;
    return true;
}



}
```

classe LoginBean

```
package br.com.view;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import br.com.amarildo.controller.UsuarioController;
import br.com.amarildo.model.UsuarioModel;
import br.com.amarildo.repository.UsuarioRepository;
import br.com.amarildo.util.NegocioException;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {
    @Inject
    private UsuarioController usuarioController;

    @Inject
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    private UsuarioModel usuarioModel;
    private String nomeLogin;
    private String numSenha;

public String login() {

    usuarioModel = usuarioRepository.ValidaUsuario(this.nomeLogin,this.numSenha);

    if (usuarioModel != null) {
        this.usuarioController.setNome(this.nomeLogin);
        this.usuarioController.setDataLogin(new Date());
        this.usuarioController.setCodigoId(usuarioModel.getCodigo());
        return "sistema/home?faces-redirect=true";
    } else if ((this.nomeLogin).isEmpty()) {
        NegocioException.MensagemAlerta("Favor informar o login!");
    } else if ((this.numSenha).isEmpty()) {
        NegocioException.MensagemAlerta("Favor informar a senha!");
    } else {
        NegocioException.MensagemErro("Usuário/senha inválidos!");
    }

    return null;
}

public String getNomeLogin() {
    return nomeLogin;
}

public void setNomeLogin(String nomeLogin) {
    this.nomeLogin = nomeLogin;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return numSenha;
}

public void setSenha(String numSenha) {
    this.numSenha = numSenha;
}
    public String Logout(){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

}
```

classe UsuarioRepository

```
package br.com.repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.amarildo.model.UsuarioModel;

public class UsuarioRepository implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private EntityManager manager;

    @Inject
    public UsuarioRepository(EntityManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public UsuarioModel porId(Long id) {
        return manager.find(UsuarioModel.class, id);
    }

    public List<UsuarioModel> todos() {
        TypedQuery<UsuarioModel> query = manager.createQuery("from UsuarioModel", UsuarioModel.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public UsuarioModel guardar(UsuarioModel usuario) {
        return this.manager.merge(usuario);
    }

    public void remover(UsuarioModel usuario) {
        this.manager.remove(usuario);
    }

    public UsuarioModel ValidaUsuario(String nomeUsuario,String senha){
        String Jpql = "Select u From UsuarioModel u Where u.nomeusuario = :usuario And u.senha = :senha";
        try {
            //Query que sera executada (Jpql)   
            TypedQuery<UsuarioModel> query = manager.createQuery(Jpql, UsuarioModel.class);
            //Parâmetros da Query
            query.setParameter("usuario", nomeUsuario);
            query.setParameter("senha", senha);
            //Retorna o Usuario se For Localizado
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

CadastroFuncionarioBean

```
    package br.com.amarildo.view;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import br.com.amarildo.controller.FuncionarioController;
import br.com.amarildo.controller.PessoaController;
import br.com.amarildo.controller.UsuarioController;
import br.com.amarildo.model.FuncionarioModel;
import br.com.amarildo.model.PessoaModel;
import br.com.amarildo.model.UsuarioModel;
import br.com.amarildo.util.NegocioException;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroFuncionarioBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private FuncionarioController funcionarioController;

    @Inject
    private PessoaController pessoaController;

    @Inject
    private UsuarioController usuarioController;

    @Inject
    private FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel;

    @Inject
    private PessoaModel pessoaModel;

    @Inject
    private UsuarioModel usuarioModel;

    private UploadedFile file;

    boolean faz = false;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicializar() {
        // Verifica se as entity PessoaModel,FuncionárioModel e UsuarioModel não está retornando null
        System.out.println("Passou Aqui no pessoaModel      !!! "+pessoaModel == null);
        System.out.println("Passou Aqui no funcionarioModel !!! "+funcionarioModel == null );
        System.out.println("Passou Aqui no UsuarioModel     !!! "+usuarioModel == null );
    }

    //Salva Registro via Input
    public void salvar() {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        try {

            //Informa que o Cadastro foi Via Input e/ou Via Xml
            if (pessoaModel.getOrigemCadastro() == "X"){
                faz = false;
                pessoaModel.getOrigemCadastro();
            }else{
                faz = true; 
                pessoaModel.setOrigemCadastro("I");
            }

            //Salvar Insert Dados de Usuário na Tabela Usuário e o Id do Objeto Usuario para Tabela Funcionario Id_Usuario
            usuarioModel = this.usuarioController.salvar(this.usuarioModel);
            this.funcionarioModel.setUsuarioModel(usuarioModel);
            this.usuarioModel = new UsuarioModel();

            //Salvar Insert Dados de Funcionário na Tabela Funcionário e o Id do Objeto Funcionário para Tabela Pessoa Id_Funcionario
            funcionarioModel = this.funcionarioController.salvar(this.funcionarioModel);
            this.pessoaModel.setFuncionarioModel(funcionarioModel);
            this.funcionarioModel = new FuncionarioModel();

            //Salvar Insert Id do Objeto Usuario que está cadastrando o Funcionario para Tabela Pessoa Id_Usuario
            usuarioModel = this.usuarioController.addId(this.usuarioController.getCodigoId());
            this.pessoaModel.setUsuarioModel(usuarioModel);         

            //Salvar Insert Dados Tabela Pessoa 
            this.pessoaController.salvar(this.pessoaModel);
            this.pessoaModel = new PessoaModel();

            if (faz){
              context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Funcionario salvo com sucesso!"));
            }

        } catch (NegocioException e) {
            FacesMessage mensagem = new FacesMessage(e.getMessage());
            mensagem.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            context.addMessage(null, mensagem);
        }

    }


    // Salva Registro via Upload
    public void UploadRegistros() throws NegocioException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            if (this.file.getFileName().equals("")) {
                NegocioException.MensagemAtencao("Nenhum arquivo selecionado!");
                return;
            }

            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = builder.parse(this.file.getInputstream());

            Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();

            NodeList nodes = element.getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodes.item(i);

                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element elementDados = (Element) node;

                    // Pegando os Elementos da entidade em Xml
                    String nome  = elementDados.getElementsByTagName("nome").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    String cargo = elementDados.getElementsByTagName("cargo").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    String usuario = elementDados.getElementsByTagName("usuario").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    String senha = elementDados.getElementsByTagName("senha").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();

                    // Informa que o Cadastro foi Upload
                    pessoaModel.setOrigemCadastro("X");

                    // Seta os dados dos Elementos em Xml
                    pessoaModel.setNome(nome);
                    funcionarioModel.setCargo(cargo);
                    usuarioModel.setNomeUsuario(usuario);
                    usuarioModel.setSenha(senha);

                    // Executa o metodo Salvar desenvolvido Acima.
                    salvar();

                }
            }

            NegocioException.MensagemInformacao("Registros cadastrados com sucesso!");

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SAXException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public FuncionarioModel getFuncionarioModel() {
        return funcionarioModel;
    }

    public void setFuncionarioModel(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) {
        this.funcionarioModel = funcionarioModel;
    }

    public PessoaModel getPessoaModel() {
        return pessoaModel;
    }

    public void setPessoaModel(PessoaModel pessoaModel) {
        this.pessoaModel = pessoaModel;
    }

    public UsuarioModel getUsuarioModel() {
        return usuarioModel;
    }

    public void setUsuarioModel(UsuarioModel usuarioModel) {
        this.usuarioModel = usuarioModel;
    }

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

bom está ai se alguém souber qual meu erro e que possa me ajudar.

segue abaixo a imagem para melhor entendimento.[image: teste]

Obrigado pela atenção de todos problema foi resolvido eu troquei o nome da minha propriedade nomeusuario para usuario na minha classe usuarioModel conforme atualizado acima, não sei porque mais no meu el ela aparecia NomeUsuario com o U maiúsculo o que causava esse erro já que ele deveria ser exatamente como a minha classe model bom mudei e resolveu.

Grato a todos

Comment: Qual o valor digitado no login que você submete e a validação não é feita?

Comment: Obrigado Giuliana, por responder. sim existe um classe login onde eu faço a validação , estou achado que de alguma forma o valor que estou digitando no login e senha para acessar o sistema, está retornado para o cadastro de login e senha , bom vou postar o código de validação de senha e cadastro caso você possa me ajudar fico muito grato.

Comment: Ao adicionar código, por favor, formate-o para melhor leitura do mesmo. Basta seleciona-lo e clicar em `{}`

Comment: Repare que na sua tela o nome está `nomeUsuario` e no seu bean está `nomeusuario`. Provavelmente é isso, corrija.

Comment: Obrigado Douglas, porem fiz como você recomendou, troquei no nome da da propriedade nomeUsuario para nomeLogin na classe LoginBean e a classe UsuarioModel ficou com a propriedade nomeUsuario e porem ainda assim o erro persiste.

Comment: Atualize os códigos na pergunta.

Comment: Um teste rápido era trocar o nome na página para `nomeusuario`. Você construiu seu projeto novamente ? Coloque um breakpoint no seu set da classe modelo e veja se passa por lá.

Comment: eu já fiz o teste tentei mudar o nome para nomeusuario na pagina mais não roda mesmo porque quando eu uso a tecla de atalho ctrl mais espaço para chamar minha propriedade a que aparece é nomeUsuario o que é muito estranho já que na minha classe model está nomeusuario minusculo